# Solr highlighting not working for a one replica

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I have two solr replicas (let's say replica A and B) with exactly same configs for highlighting. The problem i'm having is, when I query from replica A it returns results with correct highlighting tags, but when I query from replica B it returns only a list of solr IDs as "highlighting" list.

Configurations are exactly the same, Someone please give some insights to fix this issue

solr version : 4.10.4

Thanks

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your config, schema and sample queries and results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple mistake after all. Seems it didn't have loaded the configs correctly, restarting the node and reindexing solved the issue.